# Multiple inserts from same table, but 2nd insert needs identity from 1st insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-data-types

This is a contrived example to illustrate the issue :

I have a stored procedure that needs to insert in these two tables

1. `Person(ID_Person int identity, Forname varchar)`
2. `PersonExtension(ID_Person int, Age int)`

It takes a user-defined table type as a parameter, so I can pass a list of people

```
create type ListOfPeople as table
(
    Forname varchar(20),
    Age int
)
```

I want to insert into Person and PersonExtension, but the second insert needs the identity column of the first

```
create procedure MyProcedure
    @ListOfPeople ListOfPeople readonly
as
begin
    insert into Person(Forname)
    select Forname from @ListOfPeople

    insert into PersonExtension(ID_Person, Age)
    select ?, Age from @ListOfPeople
end
```

How to do this efficiently ?

Comment: I *assume* that `@data` can contain many rows (otherwise, why are you using a table type parameter)?

Comment: @Larnu I renamed `@data` to `@ListOfPeople` for clarity

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...

Comment: @Larnu it's a small list, from 2 to 30 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to *assume* that the table type parameter you have *Can* have multiple rows, due to lack of evidence to suggest it wouldn't, and that if it would only have 1 row then scalar parameters would be a much better choice.

Firstly, we need to change the definition of your table type parameter, as we need the rows to have an ID of some kind:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfPeople AS table (ID int IDENTITY, --defaults to 1,1
                                       Forename varchar(20), --Forename has an e in it
                                       Age int); --Storing the age of something is a really bad idea. Store their DoB
```

Now what we need to do is `OUTPUT` the value of the `IDENTITY` value that was created in the `INSERT` along with the value of the `ID` from your table type parameter, and insert that into a table variable. In T-SQL, you can't `OUTPUT` columns that aren't part of the `INSERT`. You *can*, however, do so with a `MERGE`. Then we can use the values insert to perform a `JOIN` and get the values:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.MyProcedure @ListOfPeople dbo.ListOfPeople READONLY AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Persons table (ID int, PID int);

    MERGE INTO Person USING @ListOfPeople AS LOP ON 1 = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (forename)
        VALUES (LOP.forename)
        OUTPUT LOP.ID, inserted.ID --Assumed Person's ID column is ID
        INTO @Persons (ID, PID);

    INSERT INTO dbo.PersonExtension(ID_Person,Age) --Again, storing Age is a bad idea
    SELECT P.PID,
           LOP.Age
    FROM @Persons P
         JOIN @ListOfPeople LOP ON P.ID = LOP.ID;

END;
```